# How do I get a label of Parent to Child relationship?

Tags: relationships, childrelationship

I am trying to get a label of Parent to Child relationship?

```
for (ChildRelationship child: Quote.sObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()) {
     System.debug(child.getRelationshipName());
}
```

but what I get is DeveloperName (Label without spaces)
ActivityHistories, QuoteLineItems and what I want is Activity Histories, Quote Line Items.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `getRelationshipName()` another methods should be used

```
for (ChildRelationship child: Quote.sObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()) {
     System.debug(child.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getLabelPlural());
}
```

Also, it is possible to get the field label like following

```
for (ChildRelationship child: Quote.sObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()) {
     System.debug(child.getField().getDescribe().getLabel());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the Label of the Relationship, but it the Plural Label of the child SObject.

For example - Asset has 3 Account field - when looking at these from Account they would all be reported as 'Asset', rather than 'Asset Provided By', 'Asset Serviced By', etc. 

Unfortunately, the relationship doesn't have a label itself - and would maybe suggest a combination of the sobject's plural label and the relationship field's label - getField().getDescribe().getLabel()

Comment: i have incorporated your suggestion in my answer